# Taylor expansion Landau

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

If a Taylor expansion is made from $n=0$ to $n=2$ is the remaining part in $O(n^2)$ or in $O(n^3)$?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it is merely $o(h^2)$. With higher regularity you can conclude it is $O(h^3)$. What might confuse you is that in numerical differential equations, we say a method whose local error term is $O(h^{k+1})$ is $k$th order; this is because there are $O(1/h)$ local errors to sum up so the global error is $O(h^k)$.